# Sharing connectionstrings between 2 .NET applications

Tags: c#, web-config, connection-string

Suppose I have an ASP.NET website running with its corresponding web.config file, which contains a bunch of connectionstrings for database access. I also have a little helper console program (deployed to the same folder as the web app) that does maintenance tasks and other stuff.  This helper programs shares a bunch of dll's with the web app, so i have to keep a separate bla.exe.config file for it so the shared dll's find the connection strings and etc.
I want to be able to make the console app use the web.config instead of having its own config file.

So far I've managed to load the appSettings at runtime (using [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration.aspx), looping through the appsettingts and adding them dynamically to the [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx) collection), but the [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx) member is apparently read-only so i cannot 'inject' the web.config's connectionstrings into it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the helper console program part of the same Visual Studio solution? If so you could consider building your config files with a NANT script.

Comment: The idea is to have a single config file to reduce maintenance cost and prevent future SNAFUs caused by differences in config files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use the [configSource attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228167.aspx) of the connectionStrings section, to reference an external file. I haven't tried it, but something like this:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="..\connnectionstrings.config">
```

connectionstrings.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="..." connectionString="Server=...;Database=..;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

---

***Update:***

The approach shown above does not work. The configSource element does not support absolute paths, or relative paths starting with "..\".

Comment: I tried the configSource approach and it seems to work. Problem is, i have to place the 'connectionstrings.config' file directly under the 'bin' directory, which kind of sucks, but is still acceptable. I'll wait to see if a better solution comes up, otherwise i'll mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would just program a way so that both applications can find the same file. I would use something like [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://Environment.SpecialFolder) using the CommonApplicationData enumeration.  You might consider the [machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28VS.71%29.aspx) file though it's generally not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question but you could consider storing the connection strings in a shared class library's `app.config` and using the method in the below SO answer to ensure that config file is always copied to the referencing project's bin folder as `shared.project.dll.config`. Then you just read `shared.project.dll.config` from the referencing project's bin folder to get the connection string.

[Visual Studio/MSBuild copy referenced class library's app.config as *.dll.config to bin folder of current project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34811381/1649501)