# Visual Studio/MSBuild copy referenced class library's app.config as *.dll.config to bin folder of current project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, app-config

I have a **class library** that is referenced by many other web application projects. It has many settings in its `app.config` that I wish to use in all of the referencing web projects. When the class library is built, it copies the `app.config` to its own `bin` folder as `<assembly.name>.dll.config`.

### How do I ensure that `<assembly.name>.dll.config` is copied to the bin folder of *each* of my referencing web application projects?

- Visual Studio / MSBuild does not seem to do this by default.
- Changing `Copy to Output Directory` or `Build Action` (in any combination) does not work.
- SlowCheetah VS extension appears to do what I want as an unintended side-effect of its config transform process, but I want to do this ***without*** any 3rd-party extensions.

---

*As an aside: It's impractical to manually put all of this config in each of the web application projects. I can read the file by looking for `<assembly.name>.dll.config` in the bin folder, and extract the settings from there. I can already do this, so that's not an issue - I just need to ensure the file is going to be there for reading*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be achieved without 3rd-party tools by adding the following to the class library's project file, `assembly.name.csproj`:

```
// Find this <Import> element for Microsoft.CSharp.targets
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
// Add this <ItemGroup> element immediately after
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="app.config">
        <Link>$(TargetName).dll.config</Link>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

This causes the `app.config` to be copied to whichever project is referencing it as `<assembly.name>.dll.config`. It's good because you only need to configure the one `.csproj` file and the effect cascades out to all referencing projects.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work with WebSite Projects but it doesn't copy the *.dll.config file over.

Comment: Awesome! I had WinFormsApp with reference to ConsoleApp and I was required to copy ConsoleApp.exe.config file to WinFormsApp output folder. I slightly modified the code above `<Link>$(TargetName).exe.config</Link>`. (`dll` changed to `exe`)

Comment: @cincua I'm not sure about Website projects, sorry. Works for Web Application project or WinFormsApp it would seem. Maybe you could try creating a Web Application project to check you've not done something wrong and confirm it's the Web Site project that's the culprit?

Comment: I can't find <Content> anywhere in the MSBuild schema reference... drilling down, <ItemGroup> only lists <Item> as its child node (which of course isn't correct).  Where did you find this solution?

Comment: @JamesKing `Item` is a generic term which can actually be called anything. The docs don't quite explain it, but you can see from their examples in the following link that any element name goes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx

E.g. you can have `CSFile`, `Compile` or `Content` or even `Stuff`. I believe the convention used by Visual Studio is to have `Compile` for things that are to be compiled and `Content` for things that are to be deployed by not compiled, judging from my own `.csproj` files.

Comment: That was what I was beginning to assume.  Some more digging came up with a list of the well-known items (though ironically, the documentation for <Content><Link>..</Link> seems incorrect :P)  Thanks!!  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629388.aspx

Comment: This works great! One side note: Although this already works by replacing the existing element for `app.config`, the configuration file will not be visible any more in the Solution Explorer. So I left the original element and just added another one with `Link` and `CopyToOutputDirectory` child elements.

Comment: I ended up with the following content for the `Link` element which works equally for `exe` and `dll` assemblies: `<Link>$(TargetFileName).config</Link>`

Answer (score 4):

### Visual Studio 2015 and earlier

For Visual Studio 2015, I am using the solution of @theyetiman (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811382/1811525)):

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.config" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="app.config">
    <Link>$(TargetFileName).config</Link>
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

(The import of `Microsoft.CSharp.targets` was already present.)

### Visual Studio 2017

During my experiments, Visual Studio 2017 seems to handle configuration files as expected out of the box. No manual modification of the project file is needed.

Comment: Visual Studio 2019 does not seem to handle it out of the box..